# How to validate the sort code to return the bank name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is out there any library or component that will check the sort code to return the bank name? For example if I want to check whether a card is visa or mastercard or if it is valid I am using card-validator https://www.npmjs.com/package/card-validator Now I want to know if there is something similar that will accept the sort code which will return the bank name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an npm module for simple sort code checking called `uk-modulus-checking` that you can find here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uk-modulus-checking

If you need more information about the bank from the sort code, there are multiple different companies that are currently selling the information either as a download, or as an API, which you'll need to pay for if you need this kind of detail:

- SortWare Sort Code Checker

  - https://www.sortcodes.co.uk/checker.html
  - https://www.sortcodes.co.uk/sort-codes-api.html
- Vocalink Extended Industry Sort Code Directory (EISCD) - https://www.vocalink.com/customer-support/eiscd/
- Bacs EISCD - https://www.bacs.co.uk/Resources/Pages/EISCD.aspx
- Sorting Codes Electronic Directory EISCD - https://www.sortingcodes.co.uk/eiscd/

Unfortunately I was not able to find a free resource.

---

Originally I misunderstood the question and provided information about getting bank information from a credit card number. That detail is below for anyone who might find that useful:

There is an online service called binlist: https://binlist.net/

And there is an npm package called `binlookup` that queries this service: https://www.npmjs.com/package/binlookup

From their docs (emphasis mine):

> Useful for querying information from a credit card such as:
>
> - brand (Visa, MasterCard, American Express, etc.)
> - expected card number length and LUHN algorithm support
> - type (debit or credit)
> - category (prepaid or classic)
> - country
> - **issuing bank**

Comment: This is very good for cards checking. But I am looking for sort codes! So in the UK when you make a payment from your account to my account you need sort code and account number. Its something like IBAN (International Bank Account Number) so this sort code and account number is used internally in the UK, where Sort Code defines the bank. So I need to know I there is a library like the one above based on sort codes. There are websites where you can check the sort codes but they don't provide any api

Comment: @MarkusHayner Ah! Sorry! Misunderstood your question, sorry about that! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thats very good but looking at prices I guess I will start to build my own sort code checker

Comment: @MarkusHayner how did you go with this? I need a library for looking up **Bank Name** by sort code, account number, etc.